# How do I trigger touchevents with an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, touch-event

In my app a user can start recording and each button they touch will be saved into an array

for example:

```
"[{"time":1835,"elemId":"bass"},{"time":2553,"elemId":"highhat"}]"
```

I then have a function which brings in the array and is supposed to playback each touch but, the code I have at the moment just brings up an error

```
document.getElementById('playback').onclick = function () {
console.log(localStorage.getItem("eventlist"));
var playback = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("eventlist"))


for (i = 0; i < playback.length; i++) {
    play = playback[i];
    setTimeout((function (play) {
        return function () {
            document.getElementById(play.elemId).touchstart();
        }
    })(play), play.time)
}
}

error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'touchstart'.
```

I would appreciate any help on this as I'm properly stuck, thanks in advance!

```
HTML:<div class="drum" id="bass" ontouchstart="play('bass');" ontouchend="touchEnd(event);">Bass</div>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest using the Web Audio API for this so you can properly time your audio events.  In any case, the error message says exactly what the problem is.  You can't call `.touchstart()` on a `<div>`.  It would be better to attach some data on that `<div>` and call something like `play(/* div data sound attribute here */`.

Comment: I'm using a plugin called LowLatencyAudio which I install through phonegap for the audio. 
I'm just not sure what to put to trigger the touch (triggering the sound)

Comment: Don't trigger the touch, call the code that plays the sound.  That's what I'm suggesting.

Comment: Well this is the code where the sound comes from.
function play(drum) {
    document.getElementById(drum).className = 'drum touched';
    lla.play('assets/' + drum + '.mp3');
   }

Comment: `lla.play()`.  That's what you should be calling.

Comment: like this " document.getElementById(play.elemId).lla.play();" ? 
That isn't working for me. The console is reading out "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'play' of undefined "

Comment: No...  `lla.play()`.  I don't know how else to describe it to you.  Stop calling `.play()` on an element.  Elements don't play things.  Your sound library does.

Comment: I know but I'm just sure how to write that out unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest embedding references to functons or string paramaters describing played instrument instead of elements' IDs. It's faster and more elegant solution.

```
"[{"time":1835,"elemId":"bass"},{"time":2553,"elemId":"highhat"}]"
```

And

```
for (i = 0; i < playback.length; i++) {
    instrument = playback[i];
    setTimeout(function (instrument) {
        play(instrument.elemId)
     }, instrument.time)
}
```